# Loading, Hiding, Show Success - UserDialog

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am using UserDialog and showing `Loading` dialog. It shows successfully, and when the network operation is done, then it dismisses itself, but ShowSuccess message dialog never pops up. Any idea?

```
public async Task SyncPopulationDataAsync(string countryId)
{
    using (Mvx.Resolve<IUserDialogs>().Loading("Loading..."))
    {
       await Task.Run(() => SyncPopulationData(countryId)).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}

 private void SyncPopulationData(string countryId)
 {
  // network operation is commented here
   if( result.exception == null)
   {
      Mvx.Resolve<IUserDialogs>().HideLoading();
      Mvx.Resolve<IUserDialogs>().ShowSuccess("Successfull", 5000);
   }
 }
```

Comment: Do you need to marshal the calls to the UI thread maybe?

Comment: @Cheesebaron, but it was working ShowSuccess by itself before I implemented Loading and HideLoading.